# How to show that every integer greater than $23$ is the sum of two squareful numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to show that every integer greater than $23$ is the sum of two squareful numbers?  I checked up to $50000$.  The argument I used in [this answer to a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/482522/1284) doesn't work because it would rely on most numbers being squareful which isn't the case.

Comment: What's a squareful number?

Comment: A squareful number is divisible by a square greater than $1$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every large enough $n$ can be represented as $n=4x+9y$, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers. Here large enough means $\ge (4-1)(9-1)$.

For completeness, we give a proof. The four numbers $24$, $25$, $26$, and $27$ are so representable. And every integer $\ge 28$ is of the shape $4k+t$, where $t$ is one of these four numbers, and $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: That's really the answer, not a hint :P +1

Comment: It could be a hint because there is no proof given... :) +1

Comment: Wait, for $n=24$, $24-9=15$, $24-2*9=6$, and $24-3*9$. So $24$ is not representable as $4x+9y$ for positive $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @nayrb: Technically, you just need that $24,\dots,27$ are of the form $4k+s$, where $s$ is a squareful number, then the rest follows by induction as André described. $24=4+20$ works just fine.